# closing and opening UL after specific li with jq comes out backward

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have PHP function which generates complected database driven li (parent-child) elements an it works great .

it's output is something like

```
<ul>
    <li id="cat_li_10" class="cat_li master_cat"> other elements inside </li>
    <li id="cat_li_9" class="cat_li master_cat"> other elements inside </li>
    <li id="cat_li_7" class="cat_li master_cat"> other elements inside </li>
    <li id="cat_li_6" class="cat_li master_cat"> other elements inside </li>
</ul>
```

I want to show my li in 4 column next to each other instead of one long one, since PHP function generates the code and I don't want to change it, I decided to use jQuery to manipulate the html code after , here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var length = Math.round(Number($('.master_cat').length) / 4 );
    var c = 0 ;
    $('.master_cat').each(function(index, element) {
        c++;
        if(c%length == 0 ){
            $(this).after('</ul><ul>');
        }
    });
});
```

but it comes out backward instead of close/open `UL` i get open/close

```
<ul class="category_ul">
<li id="cat_li_10" class="cat_li master_cat"> stuff </li>
<li id="cat_li_9" class="cat_li master_cat"> stuff </li>
<li id="cat_li_8" class="cat_li master_cat"> stuff </li>
<ul></ul>
<li id="cat_li_7" class="cat_li master_cat"> stuff </li>
<li id="cat_li_6" class="cat_li master_cat"> stuff </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First check `if(c%length == 0 )` after that `c++`

Comment: @u_mulder  it's the same , there's something wrong with `$(this).after('</ul><ul>');`

Comment: So you do `after('</ul><ul>')` and in code `<ul></ul>`. Is it a typo or this is the problem?

Comment: @u_mulder it's the problem !

Comment: Have you tried changing </ul><ul> into <ul></ul> and see if it works? Even if it would work, I dont understand why it does that.

Comment: @xCompl3x yep , first thing i've tried was this , no change !!

Comment: @max have you tried `$(this).after('</ul>').after('<ul>');`?